# Javascript pass input file to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't want to upload a file using Javascript, I just want to pass by Ajax the file to a PHP file, and in the PHP make the validations I want, plus use the `move_uploaded_file` function. Is it possible?

```
$('#the_button').on("click", function(){
    var image  = $('#image').val() == "" ? null : $('#image').files;

    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php?type=image",
        data: image,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This returns 'undefined' for the #image.

`$('#image').files[0]` also returns undefined.

`$('#image')[0].files` returns [object FileList] -> is it correct?

Comment: I do not think you can use enctype: 'multipart/form-data' with AJAX.

Comment: To upload a file to the server (PHP) you have to open the file in javascript (using the fileupload input-field) and send it as a byte[] array to the server. The server then can read the byte[] array and do with it whatever you need it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this plugin

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I've already seen that plugin..but I guess it's to much for what I want. It seems that I'm going to make it only in PHP with a form and a submit button.

Comment: Actually, I'll accept your answer. I'm currently trying to put this working and seems fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload files via AJAX.
Usual way is to set the target of your form to a hidden **iframe**.
Something like this.

```
<form target="myHiddenIframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //your form elements here. 
</form>
<iframe name="myHiddenIframe" id="myHiddenIframe" style="display: none;" />
```

Submit the form to achieve what you want.

Comment: And if I don't have any form?