# Keep input type file in a hidden input for AJAX submit

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have an input to upload an excel file and a hidden input

```
<input type="file" id="file">

<input type="hidden" id="file_submit">
```

When I choose file in input type file, I want to set its value to hidden input below and retrieve in AJAX function, then I will reset input file for next upload, prevent `ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED` error.

Here is my code in AJAX:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#file_submit').val());


$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('admin.handle-import') }}",
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(res) {
         $('file').val(''); //reset input file
    }
});
```

I tried this code to set value for hidden input:

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
    $('#file_submit').val($(this).prop('files'));
};
```

And in my controller, I get by code `$request->file;`. But it only return `"[object FileList]"`. I really don't know what I have to do now.

Can you give me a solution for this?

Thank you very much

Comment: I have no idea what a `FileList` is, but I am assuming it is sort of an array-object like element. What happens if you change to `$(this).prop('files')[0]` ? Try to also debug it yourself. Write a `debbuger;` before that line, so JS will stop there and you can manually run `$(this).prop('files')` in the chrome console and see the result, so you can understand more. Also, if you search `FileList` in google you will get the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)... There is a super really good example and explanation about how to use it !

Comment: Why not save the values in a variable instead of storing them in a hidden input?

Comment: I searched for "*file upload ajax "object FileList"*" and turned up several results here which I think answer the question, eg 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917781/parse-files-in-filelist-object, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493216/javascript-pass-input-file-to-php, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989967/when-uploading-file-via-ajax-it-always-returns-as-file-info, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491311/how-to-get-multiple-image-file-data-in-controller-of-laravel ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse files in FileList object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917781/parse-files-in-filelist-object)